# SQL Server: Casting sql_variant in a function

Tags: sql-server, function, generics, casting

I have a function which accepts two variables of type `sql_variant`. Is it possible to cast one variable as the type of the other?

For example:

```
create function test
    (@data sql_variant, @value sql_variant) 
returns sql_variant 
as
begin
    cast(@value as …(@data));   --  obviously, this is not it
    return @value;
end;
```

Is there something which will (a) get the type of `@data` and (b) allow be to cast `@value` accordingly? If possible, I would like to avoid a massive `case` block.

I might note that the function will do more, but it begins with recasting the second parameter.

Comment: There is no point in casting because the function will implicitly cast it back to `sql_variant` upon `return`. There can only be one return type, and it is declared as `sql_variant`.

Comment: @GSerg For example, if the first is a `date` column, and the second is a `date` literal, there will be some issues if I test with `case when @data=@value …` since it uses a string rather that a date. If I cast `@value` accordingly, it will work.

Comment: Comparing `datetime` variables and columns to date literals works very well and is the intended way. On contrary, comparing `sql_variant`s to date literals requires casting the `sql_variant` or the literal to a date type first. If you want to do the casting anyway, then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/30591032/11683. Which will not help you in the slightest if your function will return `sql_variant` - it will have to be casted to a date again at the calling side.

Comment: @GSerg That’s why I wondered whether I could do that from within the function.